# RDLC Report in ASP.Net - How to make a Report from unique id?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rdlc

I am a beginner with ASP.Net MVC. I made an application with 2 models (Reservations and ReservationDetails) and with the Controllers and Views.
I also made an RDLC-Report.

I added this code in my ReservationsController:

```
public ActionResult Reports(string ReportType)
{
    LocalReport localreport = new LocalReport();
    localreport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Reports/Report_Reservatie.rdlc");

    ReportDataSource reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource();
    reportDataSource.Name = "DataSet_Reservaties";
    reportDataSource.Value = storeDB.Reservaties.ToList();

    localreport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);

    string reportType = ReportType;
    string mimeType;
    string encoding;
    string fileNameExtension;

    if (reportType == "PDF")
    {
        fileNameExtension = "pdf";
    }
    else
    {
        fileNameExtension = "jpg";
    }
    string[] streams;
    Warning[] warnings;
    byte[] renderedByte;
    renderedByte = localreport.Render(reportType, "", out mimeType, out encoding, out fileNameExtension, out streams, out warnings);
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment:filename + reservaties_report." + fileNameExtension);
    return File(renderedByte, fileNameExtension);
}
```

And this in my View:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Export to PDF", "Reports", new { ReportType = "PDF" })
```

This code works, but the pfd shows all the reservations.

But I want to see the PDF with only the info from the reservation after someone made one. (And not the info from ALL the reservations.)

What is the best way to bind the report to each reservation individually?

Answer (score 0):

With caveats covering not seeing your ViewModel and other details, the key line in your controller appears to be:

```
reportDataSource.Value = storeDB.Reservaties.ToList();
```

which should almost certainly be:

```
reportDataSource.Value = storeDB.Reservaties.FirstOrDefault(a => a.IDENTIFIER == reportId);
```

where `IDENTIFIER` is the id needed to select a single report. It's not clear from your question what type (int, string, Guid) this is, but you should know. You then need to pass the `reportId` from your View to the Controller using the ViewModel, and an ActionLink such as:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Export to PDF", "Reports", "Reservations", new { ReportType = "PDF", reportId = "12345" }, null)
```

where "12345" is the `IDENTIFIER` of the report in question, which should be given by your ViewModel.

Changing the Controller Action to:

```
public ActionResult Reports(string ReportType, string reportId)
```

(or `int reportId`, or `Guid reportId` depending on the type) will allow the parameter to be passed to the Controller and be used to select the single report.

Full of caveats, without seeing a lot more code detail, and you could/should add in more validation to your Controller (to cover null or empty parameters and results), but hopefully this should set you on the path.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, RickL. I did what you said but i still get this error:    "The report data source object must be of the type System.Data.DataTable, System.Collections.IEnumerable, or System.Web.UI.IDataSource."

Comment: this is my ViewPage: 

@model int
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Checkout Complete";
}
<h2>@HojapaApplication.Resources.ResourceNL.CheckoutComplete</h2>
<p>@HojapaApplication.Resources.ResourceNL.ThankForTheOrder: @Model</p>


@Html.ActionLink("Export to PDF", "Reports", new { ReportType = "PDF", reportId = "20" }, null)